# Predicting next word using the language model tensorflow example

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

The [tensorflow tutorial](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/index.md#language_modeling) on language model allows  to compute the probability of sentences :

```
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

in the comments below it also specifies a way of predicting the next word instead of probabilities but does not specify how this can be done. So how to output a word instead of probability using this example?

```
lstm = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
# Initial state of the LSTM memory.
state = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])

loss = 0.0
for current_batch_of_words in words_in_dataset:
    # The value of state is updated after processing each batch of words.
    output, state = lstm(current_batch_of_words, state)

    # The LSTM output can be used to make next word predictions
    logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    loss += loss_function(probabilities, target_words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your output is a TensorFlow list and it is possible to get its max argument (the predicted most probable class) with a TensorFlow function. This is normally the list that contains the next word's probabilities.

At "Evaluate the Model" from this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.md#evaluate-the-model), your output list is `y` in the following example:

> First we'll figure out where we predicted the correct label. `tf.argmax`
>   is an extremely useful function which gives you the index of the
>   highest entry in a tensor along some axis. For example, `tf.argmax(y,1)`
>   is the label our model thinks is most likely for each input, while
>   `tf.argmax(y_,1)` is the true label. We can use `tf.equal` to check if our
>   prediction matches the truth.
>   `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))`

Another approach that is different is to have pre-vectorized (embedded/encoded) words. You could vectorize your words (therefore embed them) with Word2vec to accelerate learning, you might want to take a look at this. Each word could be represented as a point in a 300 dimensions space of meaning, and you could find automatically the "N words" closest to the predicted point in space at the output of the network. In that case, the `argmax` way to proceed does not work anymore and you could probably compare on cosine similarity with the words you truly wanted to compare to, but for that I am not sure actually how does this could cause numerical instabilities. In that case `y` will not represent words as features, but word embeddings over a dimensionality of, let's say, 100 to 2000 in size according to different models. You could Google something like this for more info: "man woman queen word addition word2vec" to understand the subject of embeddings more.

Note: when I talk about word2vec here, it is about using an external pre-trained word2vec model to help your training to only have pre-embedded inputs and create embedding outputs. Those outputs' corresponding words can be re-figured out by word2vec to find the corresponding similar top predicted words.

Notice that the approach I suggest is not exact since it would be only useful to know if we predict EXACTLY the word that we wanted to predict. For a more soft approach, it would be possible to use ROUGE or BLEU metrics for evaluating your model in case you use sentences or something longer than a word.

Comment: That is not the correct function for this purpose as the next most likely word given the existing sequence needs to be found.

Comment: Maybe your question was not precise enough? It seems to me that `tf.argmax(probabilities,1)` would give you the answer after the training. Giving the most likely word is what the model is trained on and therefore it is what it will _output_. You may need to tweak a little bit the index given by the function call I just gave you to get the word back from your dictionnary.

Comment: If your model was trained to predict word embedding (words represented as vectors), you need to have a tool to backward-embed your words. Word2vec and GloVe are interesting pretrained model for that reason. If your whole word dictionary is embed as a one-hot vector for each word, then the number that is outputted from my function here is the index of that word in the dictionary.

Comment: @GuillaumeChevalier @stackit Sorry just for clarification, you're saying that just by calling the command: `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))` you'll be able to predict the most likely value? `y` is going to be the sentence that you want to predict on then? Sorry I'm still having trouble going from a string where i want to predict the next word, to a valid list of words that could be next with some probability

Comment: You seem to want to predict sentences and not only single words. I would recommend you to take a look at Udacity's deep learning class in which there is an assignment where coding a word2vec model itself is done: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730/
This could help you to figure out how to code a seq2seq model for better sentence prediction with a dynamic decoder. More info here too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIR_-Xlbp7s

Comment: It may simplify things if you use an external word2vec to work with embeddings for your predictions rather than to code a list of word probabilities yourself [but I'm not quite sure however - I would read more before starting to code this].

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the argmax of the probabilities, and translate the index back to a word by reversing the word_to_id map. To get this to work, you must save the probabilities in the model and then fetch them from the run_epoch function (you could also save just the argmax itself). Here's a snippet:

```
inverseDictionary = dict(zip(word_to_id.values(), word_to_id.keys()))

def run_epoch(...):
  decodedWordId = int(np.argmax(logits))
  print (" ".join([inverseDictionary[int(x1)] for x1 in np.nditer(x)])  
    + " got" + inverseDictionary[decodedWordId] + 
    + " expected:" + inverseDictionary[int(y)])
```

See full implementation here: https://github.com/nelken/tf

Comment: Code above doesn't work with current versions of TensorFlow.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually an advantage that the function returns a probability instead of the word itself. Since it is using a list of words, with the associated probabilities, you can do further processing, and increase the accuracy of your result.

To answer your question:
You can take the list of words, iterate though it , and make the program display the word with the highest probability.

Comment: Yes I understood that can you code an example for the same? Also there is possibly a huge vocab size and iterating for each word in the vocab is practically infeasible.

Comment: Machine learning in its nature is a high computation method of solving a problem. Depending on how you are training your model, you might already be iterating over the vocab many times. On a typical machine, you can iterate over a couple million strings in a few seconds, so it might not be indefeasible. If you want to cut down on computation time (and subsequently on performance) you can implement a way to just stop iterating when you find a result with a big enough probability

Comment: During training its fine but not during production use