# Predicting the next word using the LSTM ptb model tensorflow example

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to use the tensorflow [LSTM model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#lstm) to make next word predictions.

As described in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773661/predicting-next-word-using-the-language-model-tensorflow-example) (which has no accepted answer) the example contains pseudocode to extract next word probabilities:

```
lstm = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
# Initial state of the LSTM memory.
state = tf.zeros([batch_size, lstm.state_size])

loss = 0.0
for current_batch_of_words in words_in_dataset:
  # The value of state is updated after processing each batch of words.
  output, state = lstm(current_batch_of_words, state)

  # The LSTM output can be used to make next word predictions
  logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
  probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
  loss += loss_function(probabilities, target_words)
```

I am confused about how to interpret the probabilities vector. I modified the `__init__` function of the `PTBModel` in [ptb_word_lm.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) to store the probabilities and logits:

```
class PTBModel(object):
  """The PTB model."""

  def __init__(self, is_training, config):
    # General definition of LSTM (unrolled)
    # identical to tensorflow example ...     
    # omitted for brevity ...


    # computing the logits (also from example code)
    logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(output,
                             tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [size, vocab_size]),
                             tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size]))
    loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits],
                                            [tf.reshape(self._targets, [-1])],
                                            [tf.ones([batch_size * num_steps])],
                                            vocab_size)
    self._cost = cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
    self._final_state = states[-1]

    # my addition: storing the probabilities and logits
    self.probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    self.logits = logits

    # more model definition ...
```

Then printed some info about them in the `run_epoch` function:

```
def run_epoch(session, m, data, eval_op, verbose=True):
  """Runs the model on the given data."""
  # first part of function unchanged from example

  for step, (x, y) in enumerate(reader.ptb_iterator(data, m.batch_size,
                                                    m.num_steps)):
    # evaluate proobability and logit tensors too:
    cost, state, probs, logits, _ = session.run([m.cost, m.final_state, m.probabilities, m.logits, eval_op],
                                 {m.input_data: x,
                                  m.targets: y,
                                  m.initial_state: state})
    costs += cost
    iters += m.num_steps

    if verbose and step % (epoch_size // 10) == 10:
      print("%.3f perplexity: %.3f speed: %.0f wps, n_iters: %s" %
            (step * 1.0 / epoch_size, np.exp(costs / iters),
             iters * m.batch_size / (time.time() - start_time), iters))
      chosen_word = np.argmax(probs, 1)
      print("Probabilities shape: %s, Logits shape: %s" % 
            (probs.shape, logits.shape) )
      print(chosen_word)
      print("Batch size: %s, Num steps: %s" % (m.batch_size, m.num_steps))

  return np.exp(costs / iters)
```

This produces output like this:

```
0.000 perplexity: 741.577 speed: 230 wps, n_iters: 220
(20, 10000) (20, 10000)
[ 14   1   6 589   1   5   0  87   6   5   3   5   2   2   2   2   6   2  6   1]
Batch size: 1, Num steps: 20
```

I was expecting the `probs` vector to be an array of probabilities, with one for each word in the vocabulary (eg with shape `(1, vocab_size)`), meaning that I could get the predicted word using `np.argmax(probs, 1)` as suggested in the other question.

However, the first dimension of the vector is actually equal to the number of steps in the unrolled LSTM (20 if the small config settings are used), which I'm not sure what to do with. To access to the predicted word, do I just need to use the last value (because it's the output of the final step)? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

I tried to understand how the predictions are made and evaluated by looking at the implementation of [seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py), which must perform this evaluation, but this ends up calling `gen_nn_ops._sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, which doesn't seem to be included in the github repo, so I'm not sure where else to look.

I'm quite new to both tensorflow and LSTMs, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am still looking for an answer how to predict a word using LSTM. I am also looking for working code to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `output` tensor contains the concatentation of the LSTM cell outputs for each timestep (see its definition [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5d62000743498770191bbb76ad0141989d600163/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L125)). Therefore you can find the prediction for the next word by taking `chosen_word[-1]` (or `chosen_word[sequence_length - 1]` if the sequence has been padded to match the unrolled LSTM).

The [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) op is documented in the public API under a different name. For technical reasons, it calls a generated wrapper function that does not appear in the GitHub repository. The implementation of the op is in C++, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_xent_op.h).

Comment: Why chosen_word[-1]? chosen_word is of size batch_size*num_steps. Is the model predicting one word for each step? It seems so. It seems it is predicting the next num_steps words. Is that right?

Comment: @eugenerory: The answer assumes you're only interested in the last word to be predicted, and not the intermediate ones.

Answer (score 5):

I am implementing seq2seq model too.

So lets me try to explain with my understanding:

The **outputs** of your LSTM model is a list (with length **num_steps**) of 2D tensor of size [**batch_size**, **size**].

The code line:

`output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, size])`

will produce a new **output** which is a 2D tensor of size [**batch_size** x **num_steps**, **size**].

For your case, batch_size = 1 and num_steps = 20 --> output shape is [**20**, **size**].

Code line:

`logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(output, tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [size, vocab_size]), tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size]))`

<=> **output**[batch_size x num_steps, size] x **softmax_w**[size, vocab_size] will output **logits** of size [**batch_size** x **num_steps**, **vocab_size**].
For your case, **logits** of size [**20**, **vocab_size**]
--> **probs** tensor has same size as **logits** by [**20**, **vocab_size**].

Code line:

`chosen_word = np.argmax(probs, 1)`

will output **chosen_word** tensor of size [**20**, **1**] with each value is the next prediction word index of current word.

Code line:

`loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits], [tf.reshape(self._targets, [-1])], [tf.ones([batch_size * num_steps])])`

is to compute the softmax cross entropy loss for *batch_size* of sequences.